# Create container width and font size based on height and text

Tags: xml, svg

I have the following variables:


**Container height:** 3cm

**A text:** John Smith

**A font-type:** Times New Roman



Based on those variables I'd like to create an svg document where the rendered text fits the height and the width fits the rendered text.

So in my case that'd look something like this (done manually):
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="" height="3cm" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text x="" y="" font-size="" font-family="Times New Roman" >
  John Smith
  </text>
</svg>
```

Is that in any way possible? This is my first time dealing with SVG.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do without using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is using javascript to resize the document based on the rendered text. Off the top of my head, you could do something like:

```
var elem = document.getElementById(//text id);
var height = elem.getBBox().height;
var width = elem.getBBox().width;

var svg_elem = document.getElementById(//svg id);
svg_elem.setAttributeNS(null, "width", width); 
svg_elem.setAttributeNS(null, "height", height);
```

As far as the Javascript goes, you could can place it in your html file, and run it as soon as the DOM is loaded.